# Rasterizing a simple sloped line

Tags: 3d, line, rasterization

I am aware how to rasterize a 2D line, but if I have two coordinate triplicates (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2), how can I efficiently rasterize the resulting connecting line such that the raster cell values represent the proper slope of the original points? I am willing to explore any solutions through ArcGIS, Arc Workstation, GDAL/OGR, SAGA GIS, etc.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Would you be able to **edit** your question to include the GIS software that you are using to try and do this, please?

Comment: It appears you have [accidentally created two accounts and may want to see about merging them](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

If you already have or [can create](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q8000000m3000000) the line itself as a 3D entity (ie with z values), the [Feature to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000002v000000) tool can use the z value in creating the raster.

You could also use the points to create a raster via interpolation, and then use [Extract by Mask](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002n000000) to pull out just the cells along the line. Not sure if that will take a line as a mask, but if not you could just use feature to raster as above on the line and then use that result as a mask.